Imagen no asignada en galeria. Woocommerce
Tengo una web dropshipping con woocommerce en la que se actualizan los productos e imágenes de forma automática. Las imágenes se asignan correctamente al producto ( https://i.postimg.cc/6QGZGghH/imagen-producto.png ) pero en la galería de imágenes, en la columna “subido a”, se muestran como no asignados a ninguno ( https://i.postimg.cc/xdKCQ25S/galeria-sin-adjuntar.png ).
Alguna idea?
